# In codeigniter get file list from Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I have an amazon s3 bucket that has 20+ records in it. How to get all file names with pagination support using PHP codeigniter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see two distinct possibilities: 1.) Make some attempts on your own, 2.) Hire a competent developer.

Comment: try https://github.com/fcosrno/aws-sdk-php-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get all object by listObjects

```
$result = $s3->listObjects([
    'Bucket' => 'your-bucket-name'

]);
```

it will return array of objects and with links( if your bucket is public than you can open those link else you need to use signed url or cloudfront )

And i would simply suggest you to use dataTable (it has pagination, Search ) and your record is not like 30-40k so it will work fine

As you have asked you can bucket object list by passing key and secret in constructor, i am using aws phpsdk v3

```
  s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'us-west-2',
        'credentials.ini' => [
            'key' => $credentials['key'],
            'secret' => $credentials['secret'],
        ],
   ]);
```

Now just

```
  $result = $s3->listObjects([
       'Bucket' => 'your-bucket-name'

   ]);
```

That's it you got array of all object in your bucket

Comment: Thanks, for your quick response. How to get file list using s3 bucket key and secret in php codeigniter?

Comment: well i dont know about CI  way but i can show you how to get it using php,

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. Got all objects from the bucket and I used data Table plugin.

Comment: @Anand you are welcome, if it solved your problem than please accept this answer by clicking on check mart

Comment: I would like to change text i.e. page 1 of 5 instead of 1,2,3 buttons in data Table pagination. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I dont understand can you show me example or image or something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93981/discussion-between-anand-and-nullpoite).

Comment: I would like to use http://i.imgur.com/e6wVdKm.png instead of http://i.imgur.com/ccCtcwj.png one.

Comment: No sorry i havent modified dataTable like that